# Overlay multiple widgets

Tags: c++, qt

I have one QWidget which contains a multiple sliders. All sliders resized to main QWidget size. As result all sliders share same draw rectangle. For sliders I overload `paintEvent` method, so it draw only required stuff. Here is an example code:

```
class MySlider : public QSlider
{
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event) {
        ...
    }
}

class MyWidget : public QWidget
{
        MyWidget() : QWidget() {
            slider1 = new MySlider(this);
            slider2 = new MySlider(this);

            slider1->resize(rect().width(), rect().height());
            slider2->resize(rect().width(), rect().height());
        }

        MySlider * slider1;
        MySlider * slider2;
}
```

adsf

Groove is not seen with this solution (because we don't call QSlider::paintEvent), but it still exist. For this widget it is possible to use only the last created slider (`slider2`). The rest are visible, but they are not available.

Is it possible to overlay multiple widgets on each other and still be able to access all of them with mouse event?

Answer (score 0):

Overlapping widgets isn't a good idea, expect only one is visible at the same time. What is the purpose for that overlapping?

You can set `QWidget::setAttribute(Qt::WA_TransparentForMouseEvents)` to not generate any mouse events for that particular widget so that only one slider will get that events. Then you are able to redirect that messages to your other sliders.